# Why are the properties of my partial class empty after I've run my LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online, partial-classes

I'm pulling a list of Project entities from Dynamics CRM 2011 via the SDK like so:

```
var projects = (from project in Context.ProjectSet
               where project.ModifiedOn > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1)
               select new Project
               {
                   Id = project.Id
               }).ToList();
```

This works fine and returns the correct number of projects and their id's.

The Project class was generated automatically by CrmSvcUtil.exe and is stored in a partial class like so:

**Entities.cs**
(The real file is much larger, I've cut it down)

```
[assembly: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ProxyTypesAssembly()]

namespace Framework.CRM
{
    public partial class Project : Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // There are lots of properties and events etc here
        // Here's one example of a property for brevity
        [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AttributeLogicalName("createdby")]
        public Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference CreatedBy
        {
            get
            {
                return GetAttributeValue<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference>("createdby");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Several of the auto-generated properties don't have setters so I can't store their values when I run my query. As it's auto-generated code I'm not modifying it and instead extending the class with some extra properties like so:

**CustomProperties.cs**

```
namespace Framework.CRM
{
    using System;

    public partial class Project
    {
        public Guid CustomerGuid { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }
        // It's only the nullable DateTime because CRM implements 
        // that for some reason even though it's never null
    }
}
```

I can now use the same query but this time I can store some properties that I couldn't before:

```
var projects = (from project in Context.ProjectSet
               where project.ModifiedOn > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1)
               select new Project
               {
                   Id = project.Id,
                   LastUpdated = project.ModifiedOn,
                   CustomerGuid = project.CompanylinkId != null ? project.CompanylinkId.Id : Guid.Empty
               }).ToList();
```

This still fetches the correct number of projects and the `Id` property is populated but **all of my custom properties are empty and I can't understand why**. I can guarantee you that `ModifiedOn` and `CompanylinkId` are not empty in CRM.

For example:

```
foreach (var project in projects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(project.Id.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(project.LastUpdated?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
}
```

Output:

> {40e74702-d17b-4598-b4a0-150b353459a4}
>    
>   {134aa5bd-aef3-4489-93c2-a3c0bdebd20a}

Expected:

> {40e74702-d17b-4598-b4a0-150b353459a4}
>   18/11/2016
>   {134aa5bd-aef3-4489-93c2-a3c0bdebd20a}
>   17/11/2016

What's more frustrating is that this worked last time I did it and I have the older project sat side by side with the new one and can't see what I must have done to fix it. **Am I using partial classes combined with LINQ queries incorrectly somehow?**

**Edit:**

Interestingly if I change the query to select the existing project rather than creating a new one it works just fine:

```
var projects = (from project in Context.ProjectSet
               where project.ModifiedOn > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1)
               select project).ToList();
```

I don't really want to do this as I only want about six fields out of hundreds and this is the equivalent of `select * from`.

Comment: I really don't know anything about Microsoft CRM, but you mentioned you are extending `Project` class, but in your question it looks like you are creating a new one and extending only from `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity` instead of from your auto-generated partial class. Is that correct?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure the CRM part is entirely relevant as it's a standard LINQ query from a database, the SDK just obscures some of it away but I included it for posterity. Not sure what you mean but after refactoring the code in an attempt to get this working I didn't need to declare `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity` on my partial class as that was a mistake so I've removed it. Visual Studio is definitely recognising that I'm extending the class properly, it shows me the correct places that both parts of the partial class are referenced.

Comment: I'm sorry - I just realized we are talking about partial classes and what it really means, like, in code... Never mind my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of my frustrations with the standard CrmSvcUtil generated classes.  They don't allow for setting of readonly fields, unless you retrieve the entire class, which is a bad practice.

To help overcome this issue, I wrote a change in the EarlyBoundGenerator for the XrmToolBox to "[Generate AnonymousType Constructors](https://youtu.be/p_rSBhIzE7Q?t=636)"

```
/// <summary>
/// Constructor for populating via LINQ queries given a LINQ anonymous type
/// <param name="anonymousType">LINQ anonymous type.</param>
/// </summary>
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()]
public Project(object anonymousType) : 
        this()
{
    foreach (var p in anonymousType.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var value = p.GetValue(anonymousType, null);
        var name = p.Name.ToLower();

        if (name.EndsWith("enum") && value.GetType().BaseType == typeof(System.Enum))
        {
            value = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue((int) value);
            name = name.Remove(name.Length - "enum".Length);
        }

        switch (name)
        {
            case "id":
                base.Id = (System.Guid)value;
                Attributes["projectid"] = base.Id;
                break;
            case "productid":
                var id = (System.Nullable<System.Guid>) value;
                if(id == null){ continue; }
                base.Id = id.Value;
                Attributes[name] = base.Id;
                break;
            case "formattedvalues":
                // Add Support for FormattedValues
                FormattedValues.AddRange((Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.FormattedValueCollection)value);
                break;
            default:
                Attributes[name] = value;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This then would allow you to change your query to be something like this:

```
var projects = (from project in Context.ProjectSet
               where project.ModifiedOn > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1)
               select new Project(new { 
               {
                   project.Id,
                   project.ModifiedOn,
                   project.CompanylinkId 
               }).ToList();
```

This does two great things:

1. No Need to specify the names of your attributes twice
2. Now readonly fields are able to be populated, removing the need for your custom attributes!

You can copy and paste the constructor in if you'd like, switch over to using the EarlyBoundGenerator, or to answer your question more directly as to why your values aren't getting populated, most likely it is because you aren't actually putting the values into the AttributeCollection property of the entity.  CRM does some interesting optimizations when converting from Entity to your defined type.

Comment: For anyone else interested in what Daryl was referring to he meant the option "Make Readonly Fields Editable" in the plugin named "EarlyBoundGenerator" for XrmToolBox. This solved my problem by simply using this tool to generate the classes and then altering my query as described. Awesome, thank you. Now I need to figure out why the other project works without doing this, maybe another day!

Comment: Yes, that is the other option, but you don't have to make the fields editable.  The AnonymousType Constructors allows for the setting of readonly fields, since they are all backed by the AttributesCollection.

Comment: Oh right, I'm with you now. Thankfully for the purposes of what I'm doing (this is a service hidden away from any users) I could choose the easy way out. Will bear this in mind for future use, thanks!

Comment: It's up to you as a developer, and how likely you are to shoot yourself in the foot by setting a field that is truely readonly (createdOn/ModifedOn), and getting an error at runtime, rather than compile.

Comment: Understood. On this occasion I'm simply reading the data out of CRM to push to another system and not changing anything. Certainly a fair warning to anyone else making readonly fields editable.